# Referral link using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating referral link with codeigniter but I did not get it, then I user another method by calling the last value on the referral link to appear in the form field.

> http://localhost/gwallet/register/?ref=a@a.a

I use the below code but it's not working and show empty in the input filed.

```
$idd = $this->uri->segment(3); 
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $idd; ?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed my link from http://localhost/gwallet/register/?ref=a@a.a to http://localhost/gwallet/register?id=a@a.a and also change

```
$idd = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

to

```
$idd =  $this->input->get('id');
```

Comment: $ref=  $this->input->get('ref');

Answer (score 0):

Did you load the url helper?

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```